# Log assembly version with log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using the log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender. Is there a way to add the assembly version to each entry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use thread or global context for this purpose. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx).

To answer your question better I need to know a bit more details: The version of which assembly do you want to log? Just the version of the executable (simple: just add it to the global context) or of the assembly that contains the code that logs (requires a bit more effort)?

Comment: I am referring to the version of the assembly that is calling the log function. I'll give the global context a try.

Comment: GlobalContext.Properties["assemblyVersion"] = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(); Worked. Thanks

Comment: @Josh - If you have, or think you might, have a multithreaded application, then you might consider using ThreadContext, rather than GlobalContext, to do this.  If you have logging in multiple threads and some code (in different assemblies - with different versions) in each thread puts the "assemblyVersion" property into the GlobalContext, then you might get the wrong assemblyVersion in your output.